# how to find the System.Type from a complex full path string?

Tags: c#, reflection, system.type

For example, my Type is a complex type, it is a generic type.

```
public class TestType<T> : xxx
{
}
```

this is a generic class in Assmebly A.
my Assembly B reference A, there is another type TestObject.
so the actual type is :

```
TestType<TestObject>
```

....
if i save the fullname of this type, it is a very complex string, like this:

```
BluePrint.Core.CustomObjectConverter`1[[BluePrint.SGame.VInt2, BluePrint.SGame.Plugins, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], BluePrint.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

so, if i want to find the `System.Type` of this string, how to do this?
i use `System.Type.GetType`, it return null.
the generic type and the parameter type are in different assemblies.

Comment: How did you get the full name of the type? The only way I know of requires you having a `System.Type` instance already.

Comment: i assume he tries a back and forth conversion. store the type somewhere and deserialize it later.

Comment: @Chris If that's the case, the question should mention it, because that opens up some other possibilities for problems (such as an assembly not being loaded yet in a program run when the deserialisation starts).

Answer (score 0):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the type associated with the specified name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="typeName">Full name of the type.</param>
    /// <param name="type">The type.</param>
    /// <param name="customAssemblies">Additional loaded assemblies (optional).</param>
    /// <returns>Returns <c>true</c> if the type was found; otherwise <c>false</c>.</returns>
    public static bool TryGetTypeByName(string typeName, out Type type, params Assembly[] customAssemblies)
    {
        if (typeName.Contains("Version=")
            && !typeName.Contains("`"))
        {
            // remove full qualified assembly type name
            typeName = typeName.Substring(0, typeName.IndexOf(','));
        }

        type = Type.GetType(typeName);

        if (type == null)
        {
            type = GetTypeFromAssemblies(typeName, customAssemblies);
        }

        // try get generic types
        if (type == null
            && typeName.Contains("`"))
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(typeName, "(?<MainType>.+`(?<ParamCount>[0-9]+))\\[(?<Types>.*)\\]");

            if (match.Success)
            {
                int genericParameterCount = int.Parse(match.Groups["ParamCount"].Value);
                string genericDef = match.Groups["Types"].Value;
                List<string> typeArgs = new List<string>(genericParameterCount);
                foreach (Match typeArgMatch in Regex.Matches(genericDef, "\\[(?<Type>.*?)\\],?"))
                {
                    if (typeArgMatch.Success)
                    {
                        typeArgs.Add(typeArgMatch.Groups["Type"].Value.Trim());
                    }
                }

                Type[] genericArgumentTypes = new Type[typeArgs.Count];
                for (int genTypeIndex = 0; genTypeIndex < typeArgs.Count; genTypeIndex++)
                {
                    Type genericType;
                    if (TryGetTypeByName(typeArgs[genTypeIndex], out genericType, customAssemblies))
                    {
                        genericArgumentTypes[genTypeIndex] = genericType;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // cant find generic type
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                string genericTypeString = match.Groups["MainType"].Value;
                Type genericMainType;
                if (TryGetTypeByName(genericTypeString, out genericMainType))
                {
                    // make generic type
                    type = genericMainType.MakeGenericType(genericArgumentTypes);
                }
            }
        }

        return type != null;
    }

    private static Type GetTypeFromAssemblies(string typeName, params Assembly[] customAssemblies)
    {
        Type type = null;

        if (customAssemblies != null
           && customAssemblies.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var assembly in customAssemblies)
            {
                type = assembly.GetType(typeName);

                if (type != null)
                    return type;
            }
        }

        var loadedAssemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        foreach (var assembly in loadedAssemblies)
        {
            type = assembly.GetType(typeName);

            if (type != null)
                return type;
        }

        return type;
    }
```

i have find solution here:
[Loading a generic type by name when the generics arguments come from multiple assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276384/loading-a-generic-type-by-name-when-the-generics-arguments-come-from-multiple-as)

Answer (score 0):

When you have generic types, you need to do this one step after the other.
First, get the generic type:

```
typeof(BluePrint.Core.CustomObjectConverter<>).FullName
```

this should give you

```
"BluePrint.Core.CustomObjectConverter`1"
```

you can pass this to GetType

```
var genericType = Type.GetType("BluePrint.Core.CustomObjectConverter`1")
```

and then get the specific type for it:

```
genericType.MakeGenericType("BluePrint.SGame.VInt2")
```

knowing this, and when you only have this string, you could parsing the string and building up your types one step after the next.

in case you have not yet loaded the assemblies into you space, you can use the overloads of GetType to find them: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332978(v=vs.110).aspx