# How do I get the type name of a generic type argument?

Tags: c#, generics

If I have a method signature like

```
public string myMethod<T>( ... )
```

How can I, inside the method, get the name of the type that was given as type argument? I'd like to do something similar to `typeof(T).FullName`, but that actually works...

Comment: `typeof(T).FullName` *should* work. What's happening instead?

Comment: I got compiler errors on that statement - but apparently they were caused by something else, because now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Your code should work.  `typeof(T).FullName` is perfectly valid.  This is a fully compiling, functioning program:

```
using System;

class Program 
{
    public static string MyMethod<T>()
    {
        return typeof(T).FullName;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MyMethod<int>());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
```

Running the above prints (as expected):

```
System.Int32
```

Comment: Make sure to test it with MyMethod<int>>() and see what you get...you have to account for nullable types if you care for the underlying type in that scenario.

Comment: You mean "`<int?>`"  If so, it works, but you get `System.Nullable<int>` (in full name syntax), which is what you'd expect...

Comment: Even though I already had the solution (although it didn't work for some reason...), I'll give you the rep points for writing the best answer by far =)

Comment: This just helped me since I assumed that `nameof(T)` and `typeof(T).Name` would do the same thing. Turns out `nameof(T)` just returns `T`.

Answer (score 25):

This extension method outputs the simple type name for non-generic types, and appends the list of generic arguments for generic types. This works fine for scenarios where you don't need to worry about inner generic arguments, like `IDictionary<int, IDictionary<int, string>>`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Extensions
{ 
    public static class TypeExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the type name. If this is a generic type, appends
        /// the list of generic type arguments between angle brackets.
        /// (Does not account for embedded / inner generic arguments.)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">The type.</param>
        /// <returns>System.String.</returns>
        public static string GetFormattedName(this Type type)
        {
            if(type.IsGenericType)
            {
                string genericArguments = type.GetGenericArguments()
                                    .Select(x => x.Name)
                                    .Aggregate((x1, x2) => $"{x1}, {x2}");
                return $"{type.Name.Substring(0, type.Name.IndexOf("`"))}"
                     + $"<{genericArguments}>";
            }
            return type.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use recursion and replace `.Select(x => x.Name)` with `.Select(x => x.GetFormattedName())`. This way all the types will get formatted.

Comment: Even better; `string.Join(",", type.GetGenericArguments().Select(GetFormattedName))`

Answer (score 19):

`typeof(T).Name` and `typeof(T).FullName` are working for me. I get the type passed as an argument.

Comment: ah. If the type you passed is Nullable, to get the underlying type you'd have to use something like typeof (T).GetGenericArguments()[0]

Comment: to check if the type if nullable, you'd use typeof(T).IsGenericType, and if it is, you'd use the following to get the Name or FUllName

((Type)typeof(T).GetGenericArguments()[0]).Name

Answer (score 6):

Your code should work. You can also get the name of the class instead of the full name including namespace, for example:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string GettingName<T>() => typeof(T).Name;

        public static string GettingFullName<T>() => typeof(T).FullName;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {GettingName<decimal>()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"FullName: {GettingFullName<decimal>()}");
        }
    }
}
```

Output of running above program is:

```
Name: Decimal
FullName: System.Decimal
```

[Here's a dotnet fiddle of the above code you can try out](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XbN3fT)

Answer (score 4):

```cs
private static string ExpandTypeName(Type t) =>
    !t.IsGenericType || t.IsGenericTypeDefinition
    ? !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition ? t.Name : t.Name.Remove(t.Name.IndexOf('`'))
    : $"{ExpandTypeName(t.GetGenericTypeDefinition())}<{string.Join(',', t.GetGenericArguments().Select(x => ExpandTypeName(x)))}>";
```

Comment: nice! ... you can also `.Select(ExpandTypeName)`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have some instance of a T available, it's no different than any other type.

```
var t = new T();

var name = t.GetType().FullName;
```

Comment: You don't even need an instance of T....  typeof(T) works fine with no instance...  Yours will give a different behavior if a subclass is passed into the method (as an argument)..

Comment: The problem with that code is that if T does not have a parameterless constructor then it will not work.

Comment: @Nathan - it was just an example to show getting an instance of T.  Presumably on a generic method he'll have some T type available.  @Reed - you're correct of course, I assumed that was what he was after.

Comment: Another issue would be in the case that T is an abstract class or an interface - the above code would not work.
In the case that there is a generic type constraint (the "where") then this type of code can be safe since we know the constructor and may actually have reasons to instantiate the type.
Other than that instantiation is wasteful.