# How can I get the string of a type in JavaScript/TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, templates, reflection

In C# you could do something like this :

```cs
string typeName = typeof(int).FullName;
```

And the value of `typeName` would be `System.Int32`. (Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581642/how-do-i-get-the-type-name-of-a-generic-type-argument) for reference).

So, my question is, how can I achieve the same thing in JavaScript or TypeScript?

*Please note that I do not want to get the type name from an `object`, I only want to get it from a type just like the example code above.*

Comment: i think it makes very little sense to want to do this in javascript, since ; a : Javascript is weakly typed (try doing `"1" == true`), and b : the only types javascript knows are fairly descriptive of what they are. why would you need those 6 or so types with a "strong" name?

Comment: the only thing i can find that comes close to what you are asking is doing something like `typeof Number()`, which would output *"number"* (shocking, right?)

Comment: (but don't do `typeof Number`, because that would return *"function"*)

Comment: To be frank, I actually wanted to use this feature in TypeScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the [type-name](https://www.npmjs.com/package/type-name) package in Node.js can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can use

```
typeof variable_name
```

Comment: It's not a function, it's a keyword, so the parentheses aren't needed.

Comment: @Tom yes you are right so I have corrected the answer

Comment: @Tanmay Thanks for your answer but this is not the answer I want, as I already mentioned in the question that I don't want to get the type name from an object. I want to get it directly from the type itself.

Comment: @Wong Jia Hau In Javascript there is only one way to declaring variable ie. var variable_name; So using Javascript, it is not achievable what you are trying to.

Answer (score -2):

var typeName = 5;

so you can put a simple alert in javascript.

an example like,

alert(typeof typeName);

just it.

Comment: this wouldn't work in javascript *or* typescript, and it makes no sense.

Comment: i already try many times bro, if just you want to know your variable type, just using typeof its the simpliest way.

https://codepen.io/iwanWijaya/pen/eeOmmj?editors=1111

Comment: i'm talking about the code you posted here. try running `var string typeName = 5`  in a console, or in typescript, and it will tell you there is a syntax error.

Comment: my bad, i just forgot, just put away the string word. blame on me.

Comment: @IwanWijaya While you are improving your answer. Did you ever hear of `code tags`? Or the senses of explaining things? Take a look at [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for reference.