# c# get the name of the generic type parameter in generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to get the type parameter's name (`ClassName<TypeParameterName>`) of geneic class from the class type.

for example something like this:

```
class MyClass<Type1>
{
    public Type data;
}
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(MyClass<int>).GetTypeParameterName());
    //prints: Type1
}
```

I searched a lot and didn't find anything about how to do this.
the only thing I thought of was using `StreamReader` and read the whole .cs file and find the type there in the text. But is there any faster/cleaner way to do this?

Note: I'm not trying to get the type of Type1 I'm trying to get the string "Type1".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the type name of a generic type argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581642/how-do-i-get-the-type-name-of-a-generic-type-argument)

Comment: @Lucifer No it's not. I'm not trying to get the type of T i'm trying to get the string "T"

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? It's just kind of placeholder name, you can't do much by that name.

Comment: Didn´t you write in the code, thatn it already prints out `"Type1"`. So what do you want instead? The `"int"`?

Comment: @SeM we learn c# in my school and my school has **a lot** of rules about how you should write classes and if you don't write it like this they don't read it. And I'm trying to create a method that gets a class type and returns what you need to change about the class (if you break one of the rules). Sorry for bad English

Comment: @HimBromBeere I guess it **should** do that, but does not - or do you know of a method `GetTypeParameterName()` on `Type`?

Comment: @TᴏᴍᴇʀWᴏʟʙᴇʀɢ they should give you an A just for implementing that solution. Not many students would be able to use reflection and meta-programming to implement a rule checker :-)

Comment: FYI: For the future you could also use tools like ReSharper and put your schools rule-set in there. It can do the same with a pretty UI.

Comment: @TᴏᴍᴇʀWᴏʟʙᴇʀɢ FYI2: Well, if you want to validate only your code, you can create snippets inside visual studio, for example `gclass` for generic class, and create base code the way you like.

Comment: @Toxantron I don't know what meta-programming means but I agree ;)

Comment: @SeM does it work only in Visual Studio? Because i only have notepad++.

Comment: @TᴏᴍᴇʀWᴏʟʙᴇʀɢ Yeap, it's in VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you already set the generic type parameter to `int`, so you won't get your `Type1`.

Try this:

```
class MyClass<Type1>
{
    public Type data;
}
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(typeof(MyClass<>).GetGenericArguments()[0].Name);
    //prints: Type1
}
```

Comment: Note that `typeof(MyClass<>) == typeof(MyClass<int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition()`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: so this works also: `typeof(MyClass<int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetGenericArguments()[0].Name;`

Comment: thank you, I didn't knew it's possible to do `MyClass<>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
       .
       .
       .
      //Create and object of the relevant generic class
       ClassName<string> d = new ClassName<string>();

       // Get a Type object representing the constructed type.
       Type constructed = d.GetType();

       Type generic = constructed.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
       DisplayTypeInfo(generic);
    }

    private static void DisplayTypeInfo(Type t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n{0}", t);
        Console.WriteLine("\tIs this a generic type definition? {0}", 
            t.IsGenericTypeDefinition);
        Console.WriteLine("\tIs it a generic type? {0}", 
            t.IsGenericType);
        Type[] typeArguments = t.GetGenericArguments();
        Console.WriteLine("\tList type arguments ({0}):", typeArguments.Length);
        foreach (Type tParam in typeArguments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t{0}", tParam);
        }
    }
```

Source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I say let's make it a nice extension method that works for all types, which seems to fit your scenario of code analysis.

```
static class TypeExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetGenericTypeParameterNames(this Type type) {
        if (type.IsGenericTypeDefinition) {
            return type.GetGenericArguments().Select(t => t.Name);
        } else if (type.IsGenericType) {
            return type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetGenericArguments().Select(t => t.Name);
        } else {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Now `typeof(MyClass<int>).GetGenericTypeParameterNames()` is `Type1`, while `typeof(int).GetGenericTypeParameterNames()` is empty. Use `.Where()` with whatever criterion you please to weed out "bad" names.