# Get Class Name from Expressions or Dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

We are using Entity Framework and Linq and are creating Repository methods.

If I have a generic class T, how would I obtain the actual class name, using Dynamic Linq preferably?

```
    public async Task GetTableName(T entity)
    {
        await T.
    }
```

[image: Intellisense options picture]

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I get the type name of a generic type argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581642/how-do-i-get-the-type-name-of-a-generic-type-argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like:

```
var test = typeof(T).Name;
```

You wouldn't need `Linq` for this.