# Is it possible to access the type generic T without parameters (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net

Given this example, an extension method which uses the name of the type to return a value from a dictionary by it's type using generic T.

```
public static T GetItem<T>(this Dictionary<string, object> dictionary) 
{
    var y = nameof(T);
    var z = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == y);
    return (T)z.Value;
}
```

And used as

```
var item = dictionary.GetItem<SomeClass>();
```

Is it possible to get the `nameof(T)` in the extension method above without providing any further parameters to the method? This appears to returns `T` instead of the expected `SomeClass` at runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the type name of a generic type argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581642/how-do-i-get-the-type-name-of-a-generic-type-argument)

Comment: The type is returned by `typeof` not `nameof`. `nameof` returns the name of the thing it points to. In this case, the parameter name

Comment: I also have a question, if you really have a dictionary there, why are you using it as a list/array? You should be able to write your code as `var z = dictionary[y];`, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should use

```
var y = typeof(T).Name; // y is "SomeClass"
```

or, if you want the namespace too,

```
var y = typeof(T).FullName; // y is "Namespace.For.SomeClass"
```

instead.

`nameof` will, as you discovered, return the name of the type parameter (i.e. `"T"`) and *not* the name of the type that the generic method is invoked with (i.e. `"SomeClass"`).